# Query in MySQL that get values from two tables and put them in a specific order

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I want to get values from this two tables and put them in a GridView in a specific way.
First table is estimated income and the second is actual income. 
This is the estimated income table:
[image]

and this is the actual income:
[image]

I want to get values from two tables and display them in a GridView to look like this table:
[image]

The code that i stuck in is:

```
 select t as which , SUM(Amount_income_table) as Actual, 
 SUM(estimated_amount) as Estimated
 from ((select MONTHNAME(Date_income_table) as T,
 select SUM(Amount_income_table) as Actual
 FROM bacci.income_table WHERE year(Date_income_table)='2017' GROUP BY 
 monthname(date_income_table))
 )union all
 (SELECT SUM(estimated_amount) as Estimated
 FROM bacci.estimated_income_table WHERE estimated_year='2017' GROUP BY 
 estimated_month) order by MONTHNAME(Date_income_table);
```

Comment: Hi. Tables have no order. Result sets [sic] have order. You must use ORDER BY. PS Please read & act on [mcve].

Comment: Why are you trying to union tables with different numbers of columns?

Comment: Each month i enter the value of the month so the table will show only the months that have value.

Comment: I don't know what you are talking about. If it's about union, it doesn't matter why you are trying to union tables with different numbers of columns, you can't.

Comment: Please use text for text, [don't use images/links for text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). PS How do you expect us to see what your current code is doing or check modified code? We cannot run your query, there is no text for DDL or input. Again: [mcve]. PS You are ordering the entire table. But by month name--but you don't *want* order by month name so, why? You want by month number. And the total row has to have an appropriate month ordering number. *Break your problem into parts and make each part correct before you combine/extend.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `bacci.estimated_income_table` is guaranteed to contain rows for all twelve months we want to return, and assuming `estimated_month` column is integer value 1 thru 12, I'd do something like this:

---

**EDIT**

It appears that `estimated_month` is actually the month name `January`, `February`, ... so we derive the month number (1 thru 12) from that ...

```
SELECT d.y_                                  AS `year`
     , d.mn_                                 AS `month`
     , IFNULL(SUM(d.actual),0)               AS `actual`
     , IFNULL(SUM(d.estimated),0)            AS `estimated`
  FROM (
         SELECT YEAR(it.date_income_table)                      AS `y_`
              , MONTH(it.date_income_table)                     AS `m_`
              , MONTHNAME(it.date_income_table)                 AS `mn_`
              , SUM(it.amount_income_table)                     AS `actual`
              , NULL                                            AS `estimated`
           FROM bacci.income_table it
          WHERE it.date_income_table >= '2017-01-01'
            AND it.date_income_table  < '2017-01-01' + INTERVAL 1 YEAR
          GROUP
             BY YEAR(it.date_income_table)
              , MONTH(it.date_income_table)
              , MONTHNAME(it.date_income_table)

          UNION ALL

         SELECT ei.estimated_year                               AS `y_`
              , MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(ei.estimated_month,'%M'))     AS `m_`
              , ei.estimated_month                              AS `mn_`
              , NULL                                            AS `actual`
              , SUM(ei.estimated_amount)                        AS `estimated`
           FROM bacci.estimated_income_table ei
          WHERE ei.estimated_year = '2017'
          GROUP
             BY ei.estimated_year
              , MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(ei.estimated_month,'%M'))
              , ei.estimated_month
       ) d
 GROUP
    BY d.y_
     , d.m_
     , d.mn_
 ORDER
    BY d.y_
     , d.m_
```

Comment: hi @spencer7593 when i try this Query it give me this error:
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'amount_income_table' in 'field list'

Comment: that should be `d.actual` and `d.estimated` in the outer query.  i already corrected that.

Comment: still getting an error:
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'd.estimated' in 'field list'
 im new in using Query

Comment: my bad, that needs to be a separate column.(*DOH!* i was thinking we were doing a join, and forgot we were doing a UNION ALL. I started to add in a rowsource for 1 thru 12, and then do left outer joins... but didn't do that.) Inline view `d` is corrected to return `actual` and `estimated` columns.